# Possible A Record Conflict

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, a-record

I just inherited management of the domain names from another person who resigned from my company. I am new to this type of task.

I want to map the new ip address I bought to the following example domain

*.subdomain.apps.domain.com

However when I look up the other anames in our domain, there is already an entry for *.apps.domain.com

If I add the new A Name Record for *.subdomain.apps.domain.com mapped to the new ip address will there be a conflict if a user goes to the said domain having also an A Name for *.apps.domain.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won't be a conflict. The DNS server will match the more specific record first.